# Display radio buttons inline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I am trying to display radio buttons inline in a jQuery mobile form using Rails 4. The radio button label is not formatted like other input field labels and the buttons display on separate lines. How can i display the label and buttons on a single line. The buttons are also the full width of the page instead of just wide enough to accommodate the labels.

```
<div>  
  <%= f.label :boss %>
  <%= f.radio_button :boss, false %>
  <%= f.label :boss, 'No', :value => false %>
  <%= f.radio_button :boss, true %> 
  <%= f.label :boss, 'Yes', :value => true %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wrap them into a fieldset that has an attribute **`data-tape="horizontal"`**:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Horizontal:</legend>
    <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="on" checked="checked" type="radio">
    <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">One</label>
    <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="off" type="radio">
    <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">Two</label>
    <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2c" value="other" type="radio">
    <label for="radio-choice-h-2c">Three</label>
</fieldset>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/e4cWr/